# Calculation the difference between 2 dates in SQL Server and DB2

Tags: sql, sql-server, db2, date-difference

I know there are a lot a ways to calculate the difference between to dates in different databases. My problem is that I need a way to do that that will work in both SQL Server and DB2 using the same SQL query.

On a yearly basis I can use

```
CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - [BIRTHDATE] AS AGETHISYEAR
```

But I also want to know a persons age in decimal form i.e. 34,4 depending on the persons birthday and current date.

In SQL Server the columntype for `[BIRTHDATE]` is `DATETIME` and in DB2 the column type is `DATE`.

The format is `YYYY-MM-DD`

Is there a way to do this?

Regards,
Alfred

Comment: SELECT DATEDIFF(YY, BIRTHDATE, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) will return an integer of the years, I don't understand the decimal portion, you want a fraction of the year till his next birthdate?

Comment: Do a datediff in days and divide by 365.25.  However, since sql server and db2 have different functions that give you the difference between two dates, you won't be able to use either if you want to have exactly the same sql.

Comment: I think you have your datatypes backwards - DB2 doesn't have `DATETIME`, and earlier versions of SQL Server don't have `DATE`.  You don't appear to be able to subtract dates that way in SQL Server, and doing that in DB2 results in a number containing years 10 digits out (you'd need to divide).  @DanBracuk - DB2 doesn't have `DATEDIFF`, and the `TIMESTAMPDIFF` it _does_ have returns an **estimate**.

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse U're right, I did mix the datatypes.

Answer (score 1):

I think the only way you can write a function that would work in both databases would be to use `year()`, `month()`, and `day()`, or to write functions yourself.  There is not that much overlap in the date functions between the two databases.

For instance, to get the full years between two dates, you could use:

```
select (year(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) - year(birthdate) +
        (case when month(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) * 100 + day(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) <
                   month(birthdate) * 100 + day(birthdate)
              then -1 else 0
         end)
        ) as AgeInYears
```

Fractional years would be much more complicated.  Of course, each database has its own more reasonable methods for getting what you want.  The methods are different.

Comment: Your way of calculate a persons age is good. I'll use that too (need both age based on totalt year and per actual date today) When it comes to fractional years I decided to use the 360/30-method so I simply take the year multiply it with 360 add months * 30 plus days. I do that for current_timestamp and [BIRTHDATE] subtract it and finally divide it with 360. That works perfect!

Comment: @Alfred - You are aware there's a few points where your calculation will return a person is older/younger than they really are, right?  I don't know if this is a regulatory concern for you...

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse I've been checking quite a bit and haven't found any case where the calcualted age doesn't show correct.

Comment: `(2012×360)+(12×30)+31 = 724711 = (2013×360)+(1×30)+1`.  Because you use `30` for the day (and to an extent, `360` for the year), and date falling on a `31` will appear to be the same as the first of the next month.

Comment: I don't think it's gonna be a problem but do you think it's better to use 365/31 or 365.25/30.42? @Clockwork-Muse

Comment: @Alfred - What kind of results are you looking for?  A fractional value doesn't necessarily tell you much.  Usually, people are looking for month/day values, which are based on when you start/end...

Comment: Thank you @Clockwork-Muse for your insights. I think I'll just skip the fractional value